# K8s cluster behind NAT cert

Tags: kubernetes, devops

Hi there folks I have the scenario of the picture, in which I have to create an external way to reach a kubernetes cluster been NAT to the 10.x.x.x ip address but my problem is that IP address is not related to teh certificate on the kubernetes cluster instead is tied to 192.168.100.103, so I wonder how can I add the ext IP address to the certificate without braking anything, and If I need to recreate the certificate for Kubernetes what will be the correct way to do it since this was created by a running an auto script to build the cluster, even I have plenty full access to all locally, any help will be very appreciated :)

**Scenario to solve**

[image]

Comment: How did you setup your cluster. You mentioned "runing an auto script to build the cluster" but it doesnt really tell me much. If you were using kubeadm there is a flag to pass additional ips when signing certificate. You could sign the cert manually but if there are easier options, I'd go for it first.

Comment: ok can you please be so kind to  share any doc about on how to do it ? and you are correct I'm usign kubeadm to create my cluster. txs!

Comment: Checkout [this blog](https://blog.scottlowe.org/2019/07/30/adding-a-name-to-kubernetes-api-server-certificate/) and let me know if this works for you